# Xcode 8.3 Beta No option in setting for Use Legacy Swift Language Version

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3, ios10

I developed my project in `SWIFT 2.3`, but there is one issue:
 `MPMoviePlayerController` iOS fullscreen function has wrong icon in iOS10 you can also see this in developer forums..

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/69735

I download new `Xcode 8.3` beta for check this problem, but I am not able to run my project in `Xcode 8.3` beta version, because there is no option in build setting `Use Legacy Swift Language Version`

And I read release note of Xcode8.3 beta version, here apple mention that :

```
 Xcode 8.3 no longer supports Swift 2.3. Please migrate your projects containing Swift 2.3 code to Swift 3 syntax by opening the project and choosing Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax.
```

My question is now on word is it compulsory to convert code in `Swift 3.0`? 
I am trying to convert that project in new Swift 3.0 but I am getting more then 700 error.

Can any one help me how can I convert easily?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It isn't compulsory; you can continue using Xcode 8.2 with Swift 2.3 for the time being, but if you update your device is iOS 10.3 then you will need to use Xcode 8.3 which means Swift 3. There is a function in Xcode to update your swift syntax automatically and it should fix most issues.

Comment: @Paulw11 you are right I need to check in new OS.